# Resetting Windows 8 password with a broken screen

Tags: windows-8, command-line, passwords, reset

Currently trying to get some documents off of a Windows 8 laptop with a broken screen with a password that has been forgotten. I've tried the usual trick of booting into Advanced System Options and using Command Prompt to move cmd.exe to utilman.exe so I can open it from the Ease Of Access center, but when I try and open the command prompt the computer blanks (not sure if the computer just gives up outputting to the monitor I have it hooked up to, or if it crashes for some reason). Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Given that your main goal is to get documents off the computer, the easiest thing to do is extract the harddrive from the pc, and attach it to a working system. You can then simply copy over the files. There are cheap kits available which will allow you to mount any internal harddrive as external harddrive in case you don't want to actually open your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the drive easy and hook it up to usb? Providing you have a drive bay of course or you could easily hook it up to your home PC. You could also use a password changing program that boots its own shell for example Hirens boot cd. This way you don't have to remove the drive and can make the password whatever you want.

Comment: I didn't read what you wrote in your answer to be what I wrote, otherwise I would not have posted an answer. Now that I read it again, I can somewhat understand that you wrote the same thing. Maybe next time use better wording. If I don't understand it, and I'm a tech person, OP likely won't understand it either.

Comment: That makes sense thanks for the tips. I'm sorry I came off the wrong way but I felt like you were just trying to fancy up my answer.

Comment: The reason the wording is the lack of info, I can't assume what they might have or might not have this is why I was questioning plus giving info on how possibly to fix it.